# show data in dropdown based on first dropdown selected data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two dropdowns. If I select data from first dropdown then related data (based on selected data) from second dropdown should be show. I have a code. But it is not working. Thankyou in advance.

My dropdowns are: From here I select data from one dropdown.

```
 <form class="form-inline" method="post" autocomplete="off">
<div class="vali-form">
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group2">
    <?php
    include("connection.php");
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from corporate_company ORDER BY c_name") or die (mysql_error());
    ?>      
         <label class="control-label">Select Company</label>
<select required name='cname1' id="cname1">
    <option>Select</option>
    <?php

        while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($query1))
        {   
            ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $row11['id'];?>"><?php echo $row11['c_name'];?></option>
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 form-group2">
          <label class='control-label'>Select Test</label>
  <select id="selecttest1" name="selecttest1">
 <option>Select</option>
 </select>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
        </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-send" name="submittestrelation">Submit</button>
 </form>
```

My script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#cname1").is(function(){
         var cnamee1 = $(this).val();
         $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "process-request.php",
            data: "cname12="+cnamee1,
         }).done(function(data){
             $("#selecttest1").html(data);
         });
      });
   });
```

process-request.php is:

```
<?php
 include("connection.php");
 if(isset($_POST["cname12"])){

    $cname1 = $_POST["cname12"];
    $query1=mysql_query("select * from corporate_details where c_name='$cname1'") or die (mysql_error());


    if($cname1 !== 'Select'){
echo"<option>Select test</option>";
        while($value = mysql_fetch_array($query1)) {
            ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $value['id'];?>"><?php echo $value['c_branch'];?></option>
            <?php
        }

   } 
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Replace `$("#cname1").is(function(){` with `$("#cname1").on("change", function(){` (and before posting here, at the very least do some basic debugging using `alert()`  or `console.log()`, to make sure your code is called in the first place)

Comment: Thank you very much..Its working..and thanks for suggestion.

Comment: How can I accept your answer? Here is not any option.

Comment: It's no answer, it's a comment. This question will soon be deleted, because it's extremely unlikely anybody else is going to find it useful.